# table id=table - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Server side processing of DATATABLES using Larvel 5.3

This is my JS code:

```
var users = $('.users-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{{ url('admin/adminPanleUserDataTable') }}}",
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: [0, 1, 2],
            className: 'mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'
        }]
    });
```

And this my response:

> {"draw":2,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[["taimoor","hassan","dastisupportadmin@gmail.com"]],"input":{"draw":"2","columns":[{"data":"0","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}},{"data":"1","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}},{"data":"2","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}}],"order":[{"column":"0","dir":"asc"}],"start":"0","length":"10","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"},"_":"1480405136776"}}

It is working fine on my local machine Ubuntu 16.04
but on server same Ubuntu 16.04 its is giving my Invalid JSON error.

Please help me

Comment: You didnt provide any code that is refering to laravel ,backend or php - how are we supposed to guess what's wrong? You should also ensure you did not post your actual email address / name here. Please provide more infromation about you backend code which is at url('admin/adminPanleUserDataTable')

Comment: these names and emails are not real.
Im using this https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables